# How to solve linear programming model in R

Tags: r, matrix, linear-programming

I need to solve the following microeconomic problem:

- I have six assets I can produce (asset 1 - 6) across five years (2011 - 2015).
- Each asset can only be produced during one year.
- Each asset must be produced in my five year period.
- Production is not mutually exclusive; I can produce more than one good in a year without affecting the production of either.
- Each asset has a fixed cost of production equal to 30.
- I must have non-negative profit in each year; revenues must be at least 30.

Below is a matrix representing my potential revenue for producing each asset (i) in a given year (j).

```
          2011 2012 2013 2014 2015
  Asset1    35* 37  39  42  45
  Asset2    16  17  18  19  20*
  Asset3    125 130 136*139 144
  Asset4    15  27  29  30* 33
  Asset5    14  43* 46  50  52
  Asset6    5   7   8   10  11*
```

The asterisks (`*`) represent what should be the optimal solution set.

How can I use R to solve for the production plan that maximizes my revenue (and therefore profit) subject to the constraints outlined.  My output should be a similar 6x5 matrix of `0`'s and `1`'s, where `1`'s represent choosing to produce a good in a given year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a classic problem, and one that needs to be reformulated.

Start by reformulating your problem

```
Max( sum_[i,t] (pi_[i,t] - C_[i,t]) * x_[i,t]) 
Sd. 
sum_t x_[i,t] = 1 [ for all i ]
sum_i x_[i,t] >= 30 [ for all t ]
x_[i,t] >= 0 [for all i, t]
```

In the `lpSolve` package the maximization problem is given in a linear representation, eg. in non-matrix format. Lets start by making a vector representing our `x_[i,t]`. For ease let's name it (although this is not used), just so we can keep track.

```
n <- 6
t <- 5
#x ordered by column. 
x <- c(35, 16, 125, 15, 14, 5, 37, 17, 130, 27, 43, 7, 39, 18, 136, 29, 46, 8, 42, 19, 139, 30, 50, 10, 45, 20, 144, 33, 52, 11)
# if x is matrix use:
# x <- as.vector(x)
names(x) <- paste0('x_[', seq(n), ',', rep(seq(t), each = n), ']')
head(x, n * 2)
x_[1,1] x_[2,1] x_[3,1] x_[4,1] x_[5,1] x_[6,1] x_[1,2] x_[2,2] x_[3,2] x_[4,2] x_[5,2] x_[6,2] 
     35      16     125      15      14       5      37      17     130      27      43       7
length(x)
[1] 30
```

Now now we need to create our conditions. Starting with the first condition

```
sum_t x_[i,t] = 1 [ for all i ]
```

we can create this rather simply. The thing to watch out for here, is that the dimension has to be right. We have a vector of length 30, so we'll need our conditions matrix to have 30 columns. In addition we have 6 assets, so we'll need 6 rows for this condition. Again lets name the rows and columns to keep track ourself.

```
cond1 <- matrix(0, ncol = t * n, 
                nrow = n, 
                dimnames = list(paste0('x_[', seq(n), ',t]'),
                                names(x)))
cond1[, seq(n + 1)]
        x_[1,1] x_[2,1] x_[3,1] x_[4,1] x_[5,1] x_[6,1] x_[1,2]
x_[1,t]       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
x_[2,t]       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
x_[3,t]       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
x_[4,t]       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
x_[5,t]       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
x_[6,t]       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

Next we fill our the correct fields. `x_[1,1] + x[1, 2] + ... = 1` and `x_[2,1] + x_[2,2] + ... = 1` and so forth. Using a for loop is the simplest for this problem

```
for(i in seq(n)){
  cond1[i, seq(i, 30, n)] <- 1
}
cond1[, seq(n + 1)]
        x_[1,1] x_[2,1] x_[3,1] x_[4,1] x_[5,1] x_[6,1] x_[1,2]
x_[1,t]       1       0       0       0       0       0       1
x_[2,t]       0       1       0       0       0       0       0
x_[3,t]       0       0       1       0       0       0       0
x_[4,t]       0       0       0       1       0       0       0
x_[5,t]       0       0       0       0       1       0       0
x_[6,t]       0       0       0       0       0       1       0
```

We still have to create the RHS and specify direction but I'll wait with this for now.
So next lets create our matrix for the second condition

```
sum_i x_[i,t] >= 30 [ for all t ]
```

The process for this one is very similar, but now we need a row for each period, so the dimension of the matrix is 5x30. The main difference here, is we need to insert the values of `x_[i, t]`

```
cond2 <- matrix(0, ncol = t * n, 
                nrow = t, 
                dimnames = list(paste0('t=', seq(t)),
                                names(x)))
for(i in seq(t)){
   cond2[i, seq(n) + n * (i - 1)] <- x[seq(n) + n * (i - 1)]
}
cond2[, seq(1, n * t, n)]
    x_[1,1] x_[1,2] x_[1,3] x_[1,4] x_[1,5]
t=1      35       0       0       0       0
t=2       0      37       0       0       0
t=3       0       0      39       0       0
t=4       0       0       0      42       0
t=5       0       0       0       0      45
```

Note that I'm printing the result for `x_[1, t]` to illustrate we've got it right.
Last we have the final condition. For this we note the `?lpSolve::lp` has an argument `all.bin`, and reading this, it states

> Logical: should all variables be binary? Default: FALSE.

So since all variables are either 1 or 0, we simply set this value to `TRUE`. Before continuing lets combine our conditions into one matrix

```
cond <- rbind(cond1, cond2)
```

Now both the RHS and the direction are simply taken from the 2 conditions. From the documentation on the `const.dir` argument

> Vector of character strings giving the direction of the constraint: each value should be one of "<," "<=," "=," "==," ">," or ">=". (In each pair the two values are identical.)

In our conditions we have 6 rows representing the first condition, and rows represeting condition 2. Thus we need `n` (6) times `==` and `t` (5) times `>=`.

```
cond_dir <- c(rep('==', n), rep('>=', t))
```

The RHS is created in a similar fashion

```
RHS <- c(rep(1, n), rep(30, t))
```

And that's it! Now we're ready to solve our problem using the `lpSolve::lp` function.

```
sol = lpSolve::lp(direction = 'max',
                  objective.in = x, 
                  const.mat = cond,
                  const.dir = cond_dir,
                  const.rhs = RHS,
                  all.bin = TRUE)                
sol$objval
[1] 275
```

The weights for the solution are stored in `sol$solution`

```
names(sol$solution) <- names(x)
sol$solution
x_[1,1] x_[2,1] x_[3,1] x_[4,1] x_[5,1] x_[6,1] x_[1,2] x_[2,2] x_[3,2] x_[4,2] x_[5,2] x_[6,2] x_[1,3] x_[2,3] x_[3,3] 
      1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       1 
x_[4,3] x_[5,3] x_[6,3] x_[1,4] x_[2,4] x_[3,4] x_[4,4] x_[5,4] x_[6,4] x_[1,5] x_[2,5] x_[3,5] x_[4,5] x_[5,5] x_[6,5] 
      0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       1
matrix(sol$solution, 
       ncol = t,
       dimnames = list(rownames(cond1), 
                       rownames(cond2)))
        t=1 t=2 t=3 t=4 t=5
x_[1,t]   1   0   0   0   0
x_[2,t]   0   0   0   0   1
x_[3,t]   0   0   1   0   0
x_[4,t]   0   0   0   1   0
x_[5,t]   0   1   0   0   0
x_[6,t]   0   0   0   0   1
```

Which we quickly see is the correct solution. :-)

## Side note on costs

One may have noticed "Where the hell did the costs go?". In this specific case, costs are fixed and not very interesting. This means we can ignore these during the calculations because we know the total cost is going to be `30 * 6 = 180` (which has to be substracted from the objective value). However it is not uncommon that costs depend on various factors, and might affect the optimal solution. For illustration, I'll include how we could incorporate costs in this example here.
First we'll have to extend our objective vector to incorporate the costs for each product at each period

```
Fixed_C <- -30
x <- c(x, rep(Fixed_C, n * t))
```

Next we'll add a **pseudo-constraint**

```
x_[i,t] - C_[i,t] = 0 [for all i, t]
```

This constraint ensures that if `x_[i,t] = 1` then the relevant cost is added to the problem. There's 2 ways to create this constraint. The first is to have a matrix with `n * t` rows, one for each cost and period. Alternatively we can use our first constraint and actually live with only a single constrant

```
sum_[i,t] x_[i,t] - C_[i,t] = 0
```

because our first constraint makes sure `x[1, 1] != x[1, 2]`. So our third constraint becomes

```
cond3 <- c(rep(1, n * t), rep(-1, n * t))
```

Lastly we have to extend our RHS and condition 1 and 2 matrices. Simply add 0's to the condition matrices to make the dimensions fit.

```
cond1 <- cbind(cond1, matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = n * t))
cond2 <- cbind(cond2, matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = n * t))
cond <- rbind(cond1, cond2, cond3)
cond_dir <- c(cond_dir, '==')
RHS <- c(RHS, 0)
```

And now we can once again find the optimal solution using `lpSolve::lp`

```
solC = lpSolve::lp(direction = 'max',
                  objective.in = x, 
                  const.mat = cond,
                  const.dir = cond_dir,
                  const.rhs = RHS,
                  all.bin = TRUE)
solC$objval
[1] 95
```

which is equal to our previous value `275` minus our fixed costs `Fixed_C * n = 180`.

Comment: Hey Oliver, thank you so much for answering my question. The solution is very comprehensive and it helps me to understand the model in detail!