# Minimization problem with linking constraints in R

Tags: r, matrix, linear-programming

How should I incorporate the linking constraints into the optimization problem formulation in equations 1 - 4 where Y_i's are binary variables?

```
minimize
    22X11 + 20.5X12 + 21X13 + 19X14 + 21X21 + 21X22 + 18X23 + 17X24 +
    22X31 + 24X32 + 22X33 + 23X34 + 22X41 + 16X42 + 17X43 + 17.5X44 + 
    1500 Y1 + 1700 Y2 + 1500 Y3 + 1400 Y4

subject to constraints

    2.00 X11 + 1.80 X21 + 2.30 X31 + 2.10 X41 >= 750
    2.80 X12 + 2.30 X22 + 2.20 X32 + 2.60 X42 >= 800
    1.70 X13 + 1.75 X23 + 1.60 X33 + 1.90 X43 >= 1000
    2.40 X14 + 1.90 X24 + 2.60 X34 + 2.40 X44 >= 300

    X11 - 1500 Y1 <= 0
    X21 - 2000 Y2 <= 0
    X31 - 1500 Y3 <= 0
    X41 - 1800 Y4 <= 0
    X12 - 500 Y1 >= 0
    X22 - 500 Y2 >= 0
    X32 - 500 Y3 >= 0
    X42 - 500 Y4 >= 0

    Y1 = 1 if X11>0 and 0 otherwise 
    Y1 = 1 if X12>0 and 0 otherwise 
    Y2 = 1 if X21>0 and 0 otherwise 
    Y2 = 1 if X22>0 and 0 otherwise 
    Y3 = 1 if X31>0 and 0 otherwise 
    Y3 = 1 if X32>0 and 0 otherwise 
    Y4 = 1 if X41>0 and 0 otherwise 
    Y4 = 1 if X42>0 and 0 otherwise
```

R code to find optimal solutions without those linking variables:

```
library(lpSolve)
f.obj <-  c(22,20.5,21,19,21,21,18,17,22,24,22,23,22,16,17,17.5,1500,1700,1500,1400) 

const1 = c(2.00,1.80,2.30,2.10)
const2 = c(2.80,2.30,2.20,2.60)
const3 = c(1.70,1.75,1.60,1.90)
const4 = c(2.40,1.90,2.60,2.40)

f.con <- rbind(const1,const2,const3,const4)
f.dir <- c(rep(">=",2), ">=", ">=")
f.rhs <- c(750,800,1000,300)
res <- lp("min", f.obj, f.con,f.dir,f.rhs, binary.vec=c(1,2))

res$solution
res$objective
res$objval
```

Comment: Hey chinsoon, the Xij's are positive numbers. I tried running the code and it gives me the optimal solution, but I need help in satisfying the binary variables.

Comment: But if all Yi's are 0, does that mean that my binary constraints could not be linked? Thanks for the edit!

Comment: let Ax >= b be your constraints. Your A is a 4x4 matrix but there are 16 Xij's and not 4. there is really quite a bit of issues with the formulation even without linking variables

Comment: A should be a 12x20 matrix

Comment: I made a mistake on the constraint signs, I will make an edit now

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option.

Convert X_ij's into small numbers. I just use one magnitude larger than the values seen here.

```
library(lpSolve)
n <- 20
denom <- 10e3
f.obj <- c(c(22,20.5,21,19,
    21,21,18,17,
    22,24,22,23,
    22,16,17,17.5) / denom,
    1500,1700,1500,1400) 

#identify location of variables for easy identification
vars <- c(paste0("X", c(outer(1:4, 1:4, paste0))), paste0("Y", 1:4))
vars <- setNames(seq_along(vars), vars)

#X11 X21 X31 X41 X12 X22 X32 X42 X13 X23 X33 X43 X14 X24 X34 X44  Y1  Y2  Y3  Y4 
#  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
```

Constraints as per OP while shrinking coefficients appropriately:

```
const01 <- replace(rep(0, n), 1:4, c(2.00,1.80,2.30,2.10))
const02 <- replace(rep(0, n), 5:8, c(2.80,2.30,2.20,2.60))
const03 <- replace(rep(0, n), 9:12, c(1.70,1.75,1.60,1.90))
const04 <- replace(rep(0, n), 13:16, c(2.40,1.90,2.60,2.40))

#X11, X12, Y1
const05 <- replace(rep(0, n), c(1,17), c(-1, 1500 / denom))
const06 <- replace(rep(0, n), c(5,17), c(1, -500 / denom))

#X21, X22, Y2
const07 <- replace(rep(0, n), c(2,18), c(-1, 2000 / denom))
const08 <- replace(rep(0, n), c(6,18), c(1, -500 / denom))

#X31, X32, Y3
const09 <- replace(rep(0, n), c(3,19), c(-1, 1500 / denom))
const10 <- replace(rep(0, n), c(7,19), c(1, -500 / denom))

#X41, X42, Y4
const11 <- replace(rep(0, n), c(4,20), c(-1, 1800 / denom))
const12 <- replace(rep(0, n), c(8,20), c(1, -500 / denom))
```

For linking variables, use X <= Y so that when X is non-zero, Y must be 1.

```
#X11, X12, Y1
const11 <- replace(rep(0, n), c(1,17), c(-1, 1))
const12 <- replace(rep(0, n), c(5,17), c(-1, 1))

#X21, X22, Y2
const13 <- replace(rep(0, n), c(2,18), c(-1, 1))
const14 <- replace(rep(0, n), c(6,18), c(-1, 1))

#X31, X32, Y3
const15 <- replace(rep(0, n), c(3,19), c(-1, 1))
const16 <- replace(rep(0, n), c(7,19), c(-1, 1))

#X41, X42, Y4
const17 <- replace(rep(0, n), c(4,20), c(-1, 1))
const18 <- replace(rep(0, n), c(8,20), c(-1, 1))
```

Calling the solver while shrinking RHS appropriately:

```
f.con <- do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern="^const")))
f.dir <- rep(">=", nrow(f.con))
f.rhs <- c(c(750,800,1000,300) / denom, rep(0, nrow(f.con) - 4))
res <- lp("min", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs, binary.vec=17:20)

res$solution
# [1] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.03571429 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.03076923
# [9] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.05263158 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.01153846 0.00000000
#[17] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.00000000
```

Reversing the shrinking:

```
(optval <- setNames(replace(res$solution, 1:16, denom * res$solution[1:16]), names(vars)))
```

And the optimal values:

```
     X11      X21      X31      X41      X12      X22      X32      X42      X13      X23 
  0.0000   0.0000   0.0000 357.1429   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000 307.6923   0.0000   0.0000 
     X33      X43      X14      X24      X34      X44       Y1       Y2       Y3       Y4 
  0.0000 526.3158   0.0000   0.0000 115.3846   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   1.0000
```

Obj value:

```
sum(optval * replace(f.obj, 1:16, denom * f.obj[1:16]))
#[1] 27483.29
```

Comment: As a side note, your objective value does not take `denom` into account. Seems like this should be `sum(optval * f.obj * c(rep(denom, 16), rep(1, 4))) = 41585.71`.

Comment: and it seems at least 1 of the 4 first constraints are not respected in the original problem.

Comment: @Oliver, yeah the `ls` was ordering by variable name and not the sequence intended. now we are getting the same answer

Answer (score 2):

## How should I incorporate the linking constraints to satisfy the constraints where Y1 = 1, Y2 = 2, Y3 = 3, and Y4 = 4 using Binary.vec?

I believe that you mean `Y[i] = 1 [ for i in 1:4 ]`.
The `binary.vec` argument is a

> Numeric vector like int.vec giving the indices of variables that are required to be binary.

Now the **indices** here refer to the optimization problem. Thus we need the indices to match the position of `Y[i] [for i in 1:4 ]`. In this case it's the latter 4 in your objective function, so we could get their indices as

```
binary.vec <- seq(length(f.obj), length(f.obj) - 3)
```

Note however, that your current problem is not looking for a strictly binary `Y[i]`, but further you are looking for `Y[i]` given the value of some other parameter. As it is written it is not a **linear constraint**, thus we need to do some trickery.
The problem here is that you need `Y[i] = 1 if X[i,1] > 0 and X[i, 2] > 0, 0 otherwise`, and simply adding `Y[i] %in% 0:1` won't necessarily uphold the constraints. There are several ways of getting past this, but the one I find the most intuitive is to reformulate the problem using `pseudo-parameters`

```
C * z[i, j] > x[i, j] [ for all i, j ]
z[i, j] %in% 0:1 [ for all i, j ]
C = Inf 
z[i, j] = 1 if X[i, j] > 0, 0 otherwise [ for i in 1:4, j in 1:2 ]
Y[i] <= 0.5 * z[i, 1] + 0.5 * z[i, 2]
```

The trick here is that now we have only linear constrants. Notice that if only `z[i, 1] = 1` these constraints forces `Y[i] = 0`.
We have a increased the number of parameters quite a bit, but this problem is **linear** as all equations are written in the form `y = a * x + b`.

However as I described in my answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62101306/10782538) when we add pseudo-parameters we need to

1. Extend our objective function, so it includes these as pseudo-parameters (make the solver aware of the parameters in the optimization function)
2. Extend our constraints, in order to keep dimensions correct (make the solver aware of how these affect the remaining constraints)

### Extending optimization problem

Now this is the simple part. Simply add the parameters at the end of your existing equation. I always suggest naming the objective function if one finds it hard to keep track

```
n <- length(f.obj)
names(f.obj)[seq(n - 4)] <- paste0('X[', rep(1:4, 2), ', ', rep(1:2, each = 4), ']')
names(f.obj)[-seq(n - 4)] <- paste0('Y[', 1:4, ']')
f.obj <- c(f.obj, numeric(8))
n <- length(f.obj)
names(f.obj)[seq(n - 7, n)] <- paste0('z[', rep(1:4, 2), ', ', rep(1:2, each = 4), ']')
tail(f.obj, 12)
   Y[1]    Y[2]    Y[3]    Y[4] z[1, 1] z[2, 1] z[3, 1] z[4, 1] z[1, 2] z[2, 2] z[3, 2] z[4, 2] 
   1500    1700    1500    1400       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

Note here, that they all gain a weight of 0, because their effect is captured by the effect of `X[i, j]` and `Y[i]`.

### Extend your constraints

Now this is again the tricky part. First note as in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62103286/10782538) to the previous question, that the dimensions of your constraints have to match your objective function. In this problem you have `length(f.obj)` = 28 (including the new pseudo-parameters), so **all** constraints needs to have **28** columns. The general idea here is that we (figuratively) add `sum_[i, j] 0 * X[i, j] + sum_[i] 0 * Y[i]` to every constraint. Thus your constraints should be

```
cons1 <- numeric(n)
names(cons1) <- names(f.obj)
cons12 <- cons11 <- cons10 <- cons9 <- cons8 <- cons7 <- cons6 <- cons5 <- cons4 <- cons3 <- cons2 <- cons1
cons1[1:4] <- c(2, 1.8, 2.3, 2.1)
cons2[5:8] <- c(2.8, 2.3, 2.2, 2.6)
cons3[9:12] <- c(1.7, 1.75, 1.6, 1.9)
cons4[13:16] <- c( 2.4, 1.9, 2.6, 2.4)
#X[i, j] - Cy[i] * Y[i] <= 0
cons5[c('X[1, 1]', 'Y[1]')] <- c(1, -1500)
cons6[c('X[2, 1]', 'Y[2]')] <- c(1, -2000)
cons7[c('X[3, 1]', 'Y[3]')] <- c(1, -1500)
cons8[c('X[4, 1]', 'Y[4]')] <- c(1, -1800)
cons9[c('X[1, 2]', 'Y[1]')] <- c(1, -500)
cons10[c('X[2, 2]', 'Y[2]')] <- c(1, -500)
cons11[c('X[3, 2]', 'Y[3]')] <- c(1, -500)
cons12[c('X[4, 2]', 'Y[4]')] <- c(1, -500)
#Pseudo-constraints
## Start with C * z[i, j] > x[i, j] for some very large C (here i choose 1e12, but could be any number large enough so X[i, j] does not exceed it!)
pseudo_z_1 <- numeric(n)
names(pseudo_z_1) <- names(f.obj)
pseudo_z_8 <- pseudo_z_7 <- pseudo_z_6 <- pseudo_z_5 <- pseudo_z_4 <- pseudo_z_3 <- pseudo_z_2 <- pseudo_z_1
C <- 1e12
pseudo_z_1[c('X[1, 1]', 'z[1, 1]')] <- c(-1, C)
pseudo_z_2[c('X[2, 1]', 'z[2, 1]')] <- c(-1, C)
pseudo_z_3[c('X[3, 1]', 'z[3, 1]')] <- c(-1, C)
pseudo_z_4[c('X[4, 1]', 'z[4, 1]')] <- c(-1, C)
pseudo_z_5[c('X[1, 2]', 'z[1, 2]')] <- c(-1, C)
pseudo_z_6[c('X[2, 2]', 'z[2, 2]')] <- c(-1, C)
pseudo_z_7[c('X[3, 2]', 'z[3, 2]')] <- c(-1, C)
pseudo_z_8[c('X[4, 2]', 'z[4, 2]')] <- c(-1, C)
## Next create pseudo constraints for Y[i] <= 0.5 * Z[i, 1] + 0.5 * Z[i, 2]
pseudo_y_1 <- numeric(n)
names(pseudo_y_1) <- names(f.obj)
pseudo_y_4 <- pseudo_y_3 <- pseudo_y_2 <- pseudo_y_1
pseudo_y_1[c('Y[1]', 'z[1, 1]', 'z[1, 2]')] <- c(1, -0.5, -0.5)
pseudo_y_2[c('Y[2]', 'z[2, 1]', 'z[2, 2]')] <- c(1, -0.5, -0.5)
pseudo_y_3[c('Y[3]', 'z[3, 1]', 'z[3, 2]')] <- c(1, -0.5, -0.5)
pseudo_y_4[c('Y[4]', 'z[4, 1]', 'z[4, 2]')] <- c(1, -0.5, -0.5) 
#Combine them all together
cons <- c(paste0('cons', 1:12), paste0('pseudo_z_', 1:8), paste0('pseudo_y_', 1:4))
cons.mat <- do.call(rbind, mget(cons)) #mget finds all variables given in cons.
```

Phew... Again we then have to create our `direction` and `rhs`. And we have to make sure `binary.vec` specifies `z[i, j]` as binary. Lets do this in order

```
cons.dir <- c(rep('>=', 4), rep('<=', 8), rep('>=' 8), rep('<=', 4))
names(cons.dir) <- cons
cons.rhs <- c(750, 800, 1000, 300, rep(0, 8), rep(0, 8), rep(0, 4))
#Update binary.vec to include z[i, j]
binary.vec <- c(binary.vec, seq(n, n - 7))
```

Now we should've everything set up and ready to go

```
lpSolve::lp('min', objective.in = f.obj, 
            const.mat = cons.mat,
            const.dir = cons.dir, 
            const.rhs = cons.rhs, 
            binary.vec = binary.vec)
res$objval
[1] 27483.29
names(res$solution) <- names(f.obj)
options(scipen = 999) #avoid scientific notation. Just to make it readable for us.
round(res$solution[res$solution != 0], 3)
X[4, 1] X[4, 2] X[4, 3] X[3, 4]    Y[4] z[4, 1] z[4, 2] 
357.143 307.692 526.316 115.385   1.000   1.000   1.000
```

Which seems to fit with our constraints. As this is rather much to copy-paste into R, i've added the code to [this repository](https://github.com/Bijaelo/Stackoverflow-answers), which can be loaded and executed.

#### Side note

The way I've illustrated the solution here, is a very illustrative step-by-step method. This makes it simple to follow along, but in reality one would use `for-loops` or software which allows for more naturally written constraints. If problems become a bit more complex than this, I highly encourage using an alternative package, which might also have a faster algorithm implemented.

## Should I generate the optimal solution first before satisfying the linking variables?

In your current problem you don't have any linking variables. Linking variables are usually variables obtained from a sub-optimization problem, for example

```
Max sum_i a[i] * y[i] * x[i] [for i in 1:10]
st.
y[i] %in% 0:1
x[i] = argmin{ 
  3 x[i]^2 + 4  
  st.
  x[i] != x[j] [ for all i, j ]
}
```

and in this case the standard optimization problem is not necessarily useful.

Comment: pretty crazy question ahah

Comment: its so complicated i am too lazy to check through the constraints

Comment: Going through the constraints there seems to be 0 errors in the solution I've posted (I might be blind however). So it seems to be the optimal solution.

Comment: Hey Oliver and Chinsoon, thank you so much for both of your response. I am still reading your code as I am relatively new to R.

Comment: I'm glad we could help. Feel free to ask, if anything does not seem to make much sense. :-)